# PHP Fatal error: Class 'AlbumTest\Bootstrap' not found

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I am learning framework2 and I am following this:

http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/user-guide/routing-and-controllers.html

But I'm getting this error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'AlbumTest\Bootstrap' not found in
>   /home/ben/ZendSkeletonApplication/path/to/zf2-tutorial/module/Album/test/AlbumTest/Controller/AlbumControllerTest.php
>   on line 23

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a namespace problem. Most likely your controller is in the namespace `AlbumTest` but you called `Bootstrap` instead of `\Bootstrap`. The difference is the latter will look in the root of your namespace for that directory.

Comment: Here is my AlbumControllerTest.php copied from tutorial:

Comment: <?php
namespace AlbumTest\Controller;

use AlbumTest\Bootstrap;
use Album\Controller\AlbumController;
use Zend\Http\Request;
use Zend\Http\Response;
use Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent;
use Zend\Mvc\Router\RouteMatch;
use Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\TreeRouteStack as HttpRouter;
use PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase;

class AlbumControllerTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    protected $controller;
    protected $request;
    protected $response;
    protected $routeMatch;
    protected $event;

Comment: I did it! In ../Album/test/Bootstrap.php I had to change:namespace AlbumTest;//Change this namespace for your test